# Mesaure CPU usage of python code, running through CMD

Tags: python, statistics, cpu, cpu-usage

I created a tool written in Python code, and I wanted to measure how much percentage my code is using from the CPU.

Is there a way to do this ?

I have tried several solutions online, and it just prints the current CPU usage ( as the one seen in Task Manager ).

I am expecting to exclusively see the CPU usage of my Python code running.

Comment: I'm using Windows rarely, but doesn't the Task Manager show the usage per process?

Comment: you can achieve this with the `psutil` module...

Answer (score 0):

To get the CPU of current program (your python script) you can use [Process class](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#process-class) of psutil

```py
def get_cpu_percent():
  process = psutil.Process()         ## By default gets the Process Object of current program
  cpu_usage = process.cpu_percent()  ## Gives the CPU percentage Usage
  return cpu_usage

print("CPU usage of Current Program:", get_cpu_percent())
```